# Транслитерация из нескольких полей в одно поле

Tags: jquery

Есть плагин liTranslit - jQuery Translit

Там есть возможность мгновенно переводить на транслит в другой input таким способом:

```js
$('#input-translit').liTranslit({
   elAlias: $('#input-translit-to'),
});
```

**#input-translit** - поле, куда вводятся русские символы.

**#input-translit-to** - поле, где выводятся транслит.

Суть такая:

Нужно, чтобы в поле **#input-translit-to** выводился транслит из нескольких полей.

Допустим, есть три поля: Фамилия, Имя и Отчество.

В результате должно получится: familiya-imya-otchestvo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну решение в любом случае будет костыльным, можно например так:

```
<style> #input-translit {display: none;} </style>

<textarea id="x1">имя</textarea>
<textarea id="x2">фамилия</textarea>
<textarea id="x3">Бубу</textarea>

$('#x1, #x2, #x3').on('input', function(){
  var x1 = $('#x1').val();
  var x2 = $('#x2').val();
  var x3 = $('#x3').val();    
  $('#input-translit').val( x1 + ' ' + x2 + ' ' + x3 );
  $('#input-translit').liTranslit({
      elAlias: $('#input-translit-to')
  });
});
```

Изначально поле ввода делаем невидимым, и передаем туда значения из трех других полей, при вводе.

Довольно быстро нашел, это их официальный [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yurik417/HgzfF/75/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=HgzfF), можете покопаться в коде подробнее, если есть желание.

P.s. на самом деле свой "переводчик" создать не так уж сложно, если вам будет нужна лишь простая подмена букв, без исключений и словарей...

Comment: Спасибо! На самом деле я так и пытался сделать, но делал неправильно. Делал два события вместо того, чтобы все засунуть в одно. 

Конечно, на счет своего переводчика я тоже думал, но времени особо на это нет, потому искал готовые решения)